# Names used for Audio Visualization

Tags: info-visualisation, audio

Would like to know if there are alternate names for Audio Visualization or Spectral Analysis?

Comment: At the moment, this looks like a linguistics question. If you're sure that it's a user experience question, can you rephrase it to show the user problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't related UX

Comment: @Ranjith Kurukkath https://english.stackexchange.com/ could be a helpful site, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the question is irrelevant as content design is closely related to UX. Now to answer the question:

I would say that some possible alternate names for audio visualization or spectral analysis could include:

- Sound visualization
- Frequency analysis
- Audio spectrum chart
- Sound spectrum visualization
- Frequency spectrum

These alternate names could be used to refer to the same concept in different contexts or to provide a slightly different emphasis on the specific aspects of audio visualization or spectral analysis being discussed. Ultimately, the choice of terminology will depend on the specific audience and purpose of the content.

Are you designing a product for trained audio engineers? Is it a simple audio splicing app for the general public? Based on the audience, you'd adjust the emphasis and perhaps add a tooltip or sub-header to explain what it is.